# Enqueueing an async copy from a CUDA callback - not permitted?

Tags: asynchronous, cuda, cuda-streams

This program:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

struct buffers_t {
    void* host_buffer;
    void* device_buffer;
};

void ensure_no_error(std::string message) {
    auto status = cudaGetLastError();
    if (status != cudaSuccess) {
        throw std::runtime_error(message + ": " + cudaGetErrorString(status));
    }
}

void my_callback(cudaStream_t stream, cudaError_t status, void* args) {
    auto buffers = (buffers_t *) args;
    cudaMemcpyAsync(
        buffers->host_buffer, buffers->device_buffer,
        1, cudaMemcpyDefault, stream);
    ensure_no_error("after cudaMemcpyAsync");
}

int main() {
    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    buffers_t buffers;
    cudaMallocHost(&buffers.host_buffer, 1);
    cudaMalloc(&buffers.device_buffer, 1);
    cudaStreamAddCallback(stream, my_callback, &buffers, 0);
    ensure_no_error("after enqueue callback");
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);
    ensure_no_error("after sync");
}
```

yields:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  after cudaMemcpyAsync: operation not permitted
Aborted
```

That's kind of weird, because the API reference for `cudaMemcpyAsync` does not list `cudaErrorNotPermitted` as one of the potential errors. Is there really a problem with scheduling an async copy from a callback?

Note: My machine has a GTX 650 Ti (CC 3.0), CUDA 9.0, Linux kernel 4.8.0, driver 384.59.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there really a problem with scheduling an async copy from a callback?

From the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#stream-callbacks) on stream callbacks:

> A callback must not make CUDA API calls (directly or indirectly), as it might end up waiting on itself if it makes such a call leading to a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I missed that. Actually that doesn't make a lot of sense if the call is guaranteed to by asynchronous, but ok.